# Source code for Datastax Community Edition

Tags: cassandra

What is the URL to download the source code for DataStax Community Edition??

I've been plowing through planetcassandra.org, DataStax website, and google without success. Have the Cassandra source off the Apache site...looking for the corresponding source for the DataStax community release.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The community distribution contains the corresponding Apache Cassandra release, and a free-but-not-open-source version of OpsCenter.